# Format JSON to specific table

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Given this data:

```
[
    {
        'Column': 'A',
        'Value': 10,
        'Color': 'red'
    },
    {
        'Column': 'B',
        'Value': 25,
        'Color': 'blue'
    },
        {
        'Column': 'A',
        'Value': 4,
        'Color': 'blue'
    }
]
```

I would like to create this table

```
  <table>
    <thead><td>A</td><td>B</td></thead>
    <tr>
      <td><span color='red'>10</span></td>
      <td><span color='red'></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span color='blue'>4</span></td>
      <td><span color='blue'>25</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

using KnockoutJS such that the values are data-bound.

I modified an example here but can't seem to figure out how to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ktqcvj4x/
I suspect it will involve pure computed functions to get distinct values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the array based on `Column` and a nested group based on color.

```js
const array = [
  { Column: "A", Value: 10, Color: "red" },
  { Column: "B", Value: 25, Color: "blue" },
  { Column: "A", Value: 4, Color: "blue" },
]

const group = {}

for (const { Column, Value, Color } of array) {
  if (!group[Column]) 
    group[Column] = {};
    
  group[Column][Color] = Value;
}

console.log(group)
```

This creates an object like this:

```
{
  "A": {
    "red": 10,
    "blue": 4
  },
  "B": {
    "blue": 25
  }
}
```

You can assign this to a computed property. You can also use 2 [`Set`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the all the unique `colors` and `columns`.

**HTML**:

For the headers, loop through the `columns` and create `td`. Straightforward.

For the body, you need nested loops. For each item in `colors`, create a `tr` and for each item in `columns`, create a `td`. Use [an alias in `foreach`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-3-using-as-to-give-an-alias-to-foreach-items) so that it's easier to access properties from `grouped` computed property.

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: colors, as: 'color' }">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.columns, as: 'column' }">
      <td>
        <span data-bind="style: { color: color }, 
                         text: $root.grouped()[column][color]"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Here's a working snippet. This works for any number of `columns` and `colors` in your array.

```js
function viewModel(array) {
  this.array = ko.observableArray(array);
  this.columns = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.colors = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  this.grouped = ko.computed(_ => {
    const group = {},
          columns = new Set,
          colors = new Set;

    for (const { Column, Value, Color } of array) {
      columns.add(Column)
      colors.add(Color)
      
      if (!group[Column]) 
        group[Column] = {};
        
      group[Column][Color] = Value;
    }
    
    this.columns(Array.from(columns))
    this.colors(Array.from(colors))
    return group
  })
}

const v = new viewModel([
  { Column: "A", Value: 10, Color: "red" },
  { Column: "B", Value: 25, Color: "blue" },
  { Column: "A", Value: 4, Color: "blue" },
])

ko.applyBindings(v)
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
      <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: colors, as: 'color' }">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: { data: $root.columns, as: 'column' }">
      <td>
        <span data-bind="style: { color: color }, 
                         text: $root.grouped()[column][color]"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```